# Does there exist a Laplace series for the Laplace transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I am trying to get a better understanding of what the Laplace transform is. When I learnt about the Fourier transform I found it useful to learn about the Fourier series first. Does there exist some kind of Laplace series which is to the Laplace transform what the Fourier series is to the Fourier transform?

Comment: Think of the Laplace transform as the extension of the Fourier transform to the whole s plane.  The Fourier transform itself "lives" on the $s=i\omega$ axis of the complex s plane.

Comment: Yes, it’s called the z-transform: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform

Comment: Your question has a personal element that makes your question hard to answer. How would you describe "what the Fourier series is to the Fourier transform?"

Comment: The motivation for the Laplace transform is IMO that the solutions of linear DE with constant coefficients come in the form $\sum c_ke^{\lambda_k t}$. Interpret that as a point mass measure and you can write it as integral $\int e^{st}dc(s)$. Then switch over to a real or formal density to write this as $x(t)=\int X(s)e^{st}ds$. Then contemplate the existence and form of an inverse transform. (This may have the directions switched, the coefficient computation is usually the forward transform and the function reconstruction the inverse.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Hm, no. As far as I know, the Z transform is used for discrete-time signals, while the Laplace transform, the (continuous-time) Fourier series and the (continuous-time) Fourier transform are used for continuous-time signals. The OP never talked about discrete-time signals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By introducing the [dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb),

$\sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty f(t)e^{-st}=\int_0^\infty\operatorname{\text{Ш}}_1(t)f(t)e^{-st}~dt$